# Use latin-1 encoding in nodejs querystring

Tags: node.js, express, url-encoding

Is it possible to use the latin-1 encoding (Windows 1252) for URL decoding GET-parameters, preferably via nodejs querystring or express.

I cannot change the encoding of the GET-parameters because it originates from a third party service.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use iconv or iconv-lite to use ISO 8859-1 (latin) encoding in nodejs.

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var str = iconv.decode(url, 'latin1');
```